# How add scroll grid to view all items?

Tags: qt, grid, qml, qt-quick

I have an qml file like

```
Flickable{
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight:300
    contentWidth:parent.width
    Grid {            
        id: grid
        //items
    }
}
```

I have added some items to grid. Now it works but when I move flickable to see other items, it will return old position I want to show scroll bar when scrolling and I want stop at position that is moved it and I want to be able to scroll it with mouse because I want to publish my app for desktop and mobile.

**Edit**
I changed the code like below and i added scrollbar . but it don't work

```
Rectangle{
    id:root
    color: "#90dfaa"
    Flickable{
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight:300
        contentWidth:parent.width
        y: -sb.position * grid.height
        Grid {
            id:grid
        }
    }
ScrollBar {
    id: sb
     hoverEnabled: true
    active: hovered || pressed
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    size:100// grid.height/root  .height // the probelm is here
    anchors.top: grid.top
    anchors.right: grid.right
    anchors.bottom: grid.bottom
        }
}
```

Comment: All you need is just to open the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#details) and add the line from the example to your code

Comment: Did you try to add Scrollbar? Did it work?

Comment: @folibis and demonplus i added but it don't work

Comment: @demonplus i edite question

Comment: Shouldn't the scrollbar element be just inside the Flickable?

Comment: the probelm was for setting incorrct size 100 then changed it to `grid.height/root  .height` now it works